# Install numpy Windows 8 64 with Python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, numpy, 64-bit, version

I haven't been able to install numpy on the configuration described above. If I use `pip install numpy` I get this error

```
error: Micrsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

I tried downloading the file `numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl` from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and install it but I get an error that "the wheel is not a supported wheel on this platform". I tried using `easy_install -U` and I get that "This is the wrong setup.py file to run".

Finally I found a `numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe` file here http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/ but when I double click I get that I require Python version 3.4.

Is there anyway to install numpy for Python 3.5 for Windows 64 without changing Python version?

Comment: You will need to get access to a copy 64 bit visual studio and compile it. That's the fist error you are seeing.

Comment: Since 3.5 isn't released yet, don't expect to find pre-compiled extension modules for it. You'll need a compiler to build extensions yourself. For CPython 3.5 on Windows, you can use Visual Studio 2015, Community Edition. Unfortunately it isn't as simple as installing a C/C++ compiler. You'll find that often there are dependencies that you need to build or install, which can get tediously complicated. And you may even need compilers for other languages, such as Fortran.

Comment: Now that 3.5 has been released I tried installing using pip and from source code with Visual Studio 2015.  On both occasions it failed with `ValueError: Could not lock sequences (None)`.  Looking at the source code, the issue appears to be with the long double representation in Visual Studio 2015.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about Numpy to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into many similar problems before. Windows seems a little uncooperative when it deals with python. Any who, I chanced upon what proves so far to be a cure-all method for installing external libraries (I've done this with well over 10 of them, numpy included). Basically, download 7-zip, and download the zipped version of the file (usually the default from the source or sourceforge).Once downloaded, open the file in the file explorer, unzip it TWICE, and navigate until you see something like 'setup.py'. Then, hold shift and right-click in file explorer, and select 'open command line here'. From there, simply type 'setup.py install' and voila. Worked for me on all external libraries so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install numpy using the package manager [Conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/index.html).

I advise you to install [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda). It contains Python and the Conda package manager.

```
conda create --name py35numpy python=3.5 numpy
```

With this command you create a virtualenv with the name py35numpy, with the 3.5 version of Python and install the numpy package with all its dependencies.

Activate the virtual environment.

On Windows: `activate py35numpy`